# Caliburn.Micro Navigation causing StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to set up navigation in an MVVM app using Caliburn.Micro and its `SimpleContainer` class. I need to inject my `ShellViewModel` into the `Navigator` for it to access the `ActivateItem()` method. When the shell view first loads it needs to activate the first child view (`CourseListViewModel`). To perform this initial navigation I'm trying to inject the `Navigator` into my `ShellViewModel`. The problem is this causes a `StackOverflowException` because the `ShellViewModel` constructor requires a `Navigator` which requires a `ShellViewModel` and so on.

When I configured the `SimpleContainer` I registered the `ShellViewModel` using the `Singleton()` method. My understanding was that the container would then create an instance of the `ShellViewModel` the first time it's requested, and then return the same instance for any subsequent requests despite the fact that my `ShellViewModel` doesn't actually implement the Singleton pattern. Because of this, I only expected the `ShellViewModel` constructor to be called once, but this clearly isn't what's happening.

**Bootstrapper**

```
class Bootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{
    public Bootstrapper()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor<IShell>();
    }

    private readonly SimpleContainer _container = new SimpleContainer();

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        _container.Instance(_container);
        
        _container.Singleton<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>()
                    .Singleton<IWindowManager, WindowManager>()
                    .Singleton<INavigator, Navigator>() // << Navigator is registered as a Singleton
                    .Singleton<IShell, ShellViewModel>() // << ShellViewModel is registered as a Singleton
                    .Singleton<Models.GoogleClassroom>();

        // Register all ViewModels
        GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
            .Where(type => type.IsClass)
            .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("ViewModel"))
            .Where(type => type.Name != "ShellViewModel") // Avoid registering ShellViewModel as a PerRequest instance
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(type => _container.RegisterPerRequest(type, null, type));

    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string key)
    {
        return _container.GetInstance(service, key);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return _container.GetAllInstances(service);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        _container.BuildUp(instance);
    }
}
```

**Navigator**

```
public class Navigator : INavigator
{
    private readonly IShell _shell;
    private readonly IWindowManager _windowManager;

    public Navigator(IShell shell, IWindowManager windowManager)
    {
        _shell = shell;
        _windowManager = windowManager;
    }

    // I can provide the rest of the methods if necessary but the exception occurs in the

}
```

**ShellViewModel**

```
public interface IShell : IConductActiveItem { }

public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>.Collection.OneActive, IHandle<object>, IShell
{

    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private readonly IWindowManager _windowManager;
    private readonly INavigator _navigator;

    public ShellViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager, IEventAggregator eventAggregator, INavigator navigator)
    {
        _windowManager = windowManager;
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
        _navigator = navigator;

        // Activate the initial child view
        _navigator.To<CourseListViewModel>().Go();

    }
}
```

I stepped through the application and found that the `StackOverflowException` occurred when the `protected override object GetInstance()` method tried to get an instance of type `IShell`, but because of the way I believed the `_container.Singleton()` registration worked it took me a little while to figure out what was happening. While trying to debug it I removed the `Navigator` from the `ShellViewModel` constructor and injected the conductor itself instead. Then I tried to activate the initial child view as below:

```
public ShellViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager, IEventAggregator eventAggregator, SimpleContainer container) // INavigator navigator)
{
    // Code shortened, but same as above
    
    // GetInstance<IShell>() calls this constructor recursively
    container.GetInstance<IShell>().ActivateItem(container.GetInstance<CourseListViewModel>());

}
```

As you can see in the comments, this is where I spotted the problem. The `ShellViewModel` constructor is being called recursively instead of the conductor injecting an existing object (Singleton) as I expected.

My question is have I misunderstood what `SimpleContainer.Singleton()` does or have I used it incorrectly? and what is the correct way to implement this to resolve my problem with the initial navigation and still inject the dependencies to it?

Comment: You've created a circular dependency and will need to introduce something to break it.  You could create another service that manages the relationship between those two - something that registers views and navigators for example, or a factory class that creates one (with the other being passed into the method), etc.  There's lot of options.  In this case maybe the navigator could be the factory and create the views?

Comment: I couldn't understand how I had created a circular dependency because the `ShellViewModel` is registered as a Singleton and the constructor should only be called once. I was thinking that the Navigator would then get the singleton instance injected into it. But I've just spotted my mistake in that logic. The Navigator is instantiated for the shell view constructor I.e. before the constructor completes, so the first instance of `ShellViewModel` doesn't exist yet and cannot be injected into the Navigator, hence the loop. I will look at implementing one of your suggestions, thank you.

Comment: @Daniel: How would you instantiate a `Navigator` yourself (without a container) without first creating an `IShell`? And how would you create the `IShell` without creating a `Navigator` first? Catch 22.